# Regular expression for word with specific prefix/suffix

Tags: python, regex

i want to match the word only if the word is surrounded with a maximum of 1 wild character on either side followed by space or nothing on either side. for example I want ring to match 'ring' , ' ring' , ' tring', 'ring ', ' ringt', '' ringt ', ' ring  ', 'tringt ', 'tringt '

but not:
'ttring', 'ringttt', 'ttringtt'

so far I have:

`[?\s\S]ring[?\s\S][?!\s]`

any suggestions?

Comment: Are they inside of a larger text? or each separated as a single input?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/1Q4HuD/1 ?

Comment: *1 wild character* - elaborate,  should it be the same char ? Also, post your input structure : list or string

Comment: they are inside a larger text for example " i went to the store and bought ring"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, this should do:

```
(?:^|\s)\S?ring\S?(?:\s|$)
```

- `(?:^|\s)` - this non-capturing group makes sure that the pattern is preceded by a whitespace or at the beginning
- `\S?` matches zero or one non-whitespace character
- `ring` matches literal `ring`
- `(?:\s|$)` - the zero width positive lookahead makes sure the match is preceded by a space or is at the end

**Example:**

```
In [92]: l = ['ring ', ' ringt', ' ringt ', ' ring ', \
              'tringt ', 'tringt ',  'ttring', 'ringttt', 'ttringtt']

In [93]: list(filter(lambda s: re.search(r'(?:^|\s)\S?ring\S?(?:\s|$)', s), l))
Out[93]: ['ring ', ' ringt', ' ringt ', ' ring ', 'tringt ', 'tringt ']
```